# Cyberattacks on Small- Medium Business?

Tags: business, security

Does anyone have a dataset of type of cyber attack, amount of attacks and damage on SME's?

Edit:
The possible duplicate [Public Datasets on Data Breach](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5273/public-datasets-on-data-breach) didn't really help me because it's about databreaches and it only says "hacked" or "incidental leak" etc. I'm looking for info about SMB's that got hacked, or attempted hacked (by APT's), got infected with malware, got attacked by DDoS, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Public Datasets on Data Breach](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5273/public-datasets-on-data-breach)